# How to disable the auto scroll to the top of the screen when coming back to the list from another view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Hi I have a question about swiftUI. As shown in the images below, I have a list of words that lead to another view. The problem is that when you tap the back button on the WordDetailView and go back to the List view you are at the TOP of the list. I want the users to be at the same position as they first tapped the word. How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.
[image: List View]
[image: WordDetailView]

```
NavigationStack {
List {
     ForEach(uniqueWords.sorted(), id: \.self) { unique in
         NavigationLink(destination: WordDetailView(listing: unique)) {
             HStack {
                ListingItemView(listing: unique)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        getUniqueWords() // get the words to show
                    }
}
```

Comment: Try looking into using [ScrollViewProxy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewproxy) with [scrollTo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewproxy/scrollto(_:anchor:)). For example: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-scroll-to-a-specific-row-in-a-list

 Or try using `List selection`  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list#Supporting-selection-in-lists

Answer (score 1):

You could try moving the `.onAppear{...}` outside of the `NavigationStack`.
Currently the `.onAppear{...}`, gets called when you come back from the
other view (and updates the view), but not if you have it outside of the `NavigationStack`.

```
 NavigationStack {
     List {
         ForEach(uniqueWords.sorted(), id: \.self) { unique in
             NavigationLink(destination: WordDetailView(listing: unique)) {
                 HStack {
                     ListingItemView(listing: unique)
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
 .onAppear {  // <--- here, outside the NavigationStack
     getUniqueWords() // get the words to show
 }
```